# organization find all children algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

So i am creating a system where users are able to build their own organization structure meaning that all organizations will most likely be different.

My setup is that an organization consists of different divisions. In my `division` table i have a value called `parent_id` that points to a division who is the current divisions parent.

a setup might look something like this (Paint drawing)

[image]

as you can see from the drawing `division` 2 and 3 are children of `division` 1 therefore they both have the value `parent_id = 1`

division 4 is a child of id 2 and has two children (5 & 6)

now to the tricky part because of the structure in my system i need access to all children and the childrens children in my system depending on a root node.

So for example if i want to know all of the children of `division` 1 the result should be `[2,3,4,5,6]`

Now my question is. how will i find all children connected?

At first i thought something like this

```
 root = 1;
while(getChildren(root) != null)
{

}

function getChildren(root)
{
  var result =  'select * from division where parent_id = '+root;
    if(result != null)
    {
        root = result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

*please note this is only an example of using a while loop to get through the list*

However this would not work when the result of the statement returns two children

So my question is how do i find all children of any root id with the above setup?

Comment: Are you looking for a DB query?  Code?  What language and/or database system?

Comment: Does the order in which nodes are returned matter? That is, if you ask for all children of node 1, could I return `{2, 4, 5, 6, 3}`? Do you want them in order by node id? Highest-level nodes first? Depth-first (as in my example)? Also, are these nodes in a database or do you have the entire tree structure in memory?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a recursive function.  Be careful, and keep track of the children you have found so if you run into them again you stop and error - otherwise you will end up in an infinite loop.

I don't know what language you are using, so here's some psuedocode:

```
create dictionaryOfDivisions
dictionaryOfDivisions.Add(currentDivision)
GetChildren(currentDivision)

Function GetChildren(thisDivision) {
    theseChildren = GetChildrenFromDB(thisDivision)
    For each child in theseChildren 
       If dictionaryOfDivisions.Exists(child)
           'Oops, here's a loop! Error
           Exit
       Else
            dictionaryOfDivisions.Add(child)
            GetChildren(child)
       End If
    Next
}
```

Comment: Why would you need the test to see if the child already exists in the dictionary? If the data is correct (i.e. no child has more than one parent node), then the recursive function can never visit any node more than once. So the existence check is not necessary.